# AnguLar JS Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs

I have created separate factoryservice file so that I can use & set variable inside it and  can use variables in dependent controllers .

I am getting  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: error getMemberProvider ,

I have already linked this file in index.html , I checked spelling which is also correct of my factoryservice name.

My xyz-service.js file looks like below:-

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('cntrl1').factory('getMember', function(Datamember) {
  var Datamember;
  var addMethod = function(Datamember) {
    Datamember = Datamember;
  }
  return {
    setPolicyNumber: function(Datamember) {
      addMethod(Datamember);
    },
    getMember: function() {
      return Datamember;
    }
  };
});
```

I have already injected the facrotyservice in another controller where I want to use it.Still the same issue and I can't find the xyz-service.js in network tab under developer options even though I had added this file in index.html.

Your help is appreciated.

Regards,
TMLS

Comment: How **exactly** have you _"linked this file in index.html"_? If you're not seeing a network request for it, perhaps you haven't saved `index.html`

Comment: Hi Phil , Thanks.I referenced this file  xyz-service.js in index.html like this:  <script src="scripts/services/xyz-service.js"></script>

Comment: Then you should definitely see a network request for it. Are you sure you're looking at the right file? Try _"View Source"_ in your browser to make sure

Comment: Hi Phil ,I can't see xyz-service.js in pagesource.I checked the war package which I am deploying on web server which has the js file which I had added in index.html . Is it cache issue of browser ? because on server I can see that js in pagesource but on my machine , I can't.

Comment: Hi Phil ,Thanks for direction . Issue was with browser cache .I cleared cache and temporary files.Issue Resolved!

Comment: If you are using Firefox, you can user [Ctrl+Shift+R](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1073264) to do a refresh bypassing the cache. In that case manual explicit clearing of cache wont be required every time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Phil for guidance!
Issue was with browser cache , I cleared it and temporary files  and everything was fine later on.